# Fill the data in matrix by matching vactor and column name in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix that contains persons names(as row names) and  product ID(as column names) and I have different files each file contains product name & product ID used by a single person.

This is the structure of matrix (res):-
[image]

This is the file for Noah :-

```
Product_name    product_ID
A               p-0001
C               p-0002
J               p-0010
AX              p-0054
RD              p-0059
TW              p-0067
YZ              p-0099
```

This is my code :-

```
listfile                                     #contain list of all files
ID                                           #contain ID of all products
N <- read.csv("/home/folder/Noah.csv")
N_ID <- N$product_ID                         #contain Noah's product IDs
res <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(listfile), ncol = nrow(ID),dimnames =
list(unlist(listfile), unlist(ID)))          # create matrix res
for(j in 1:length(colnames(res))){
if(N_id %in% j){
paste(1,res)
} else {
paste(0,res)
}
```

I am trying to put all files data as matrix. If a person use that product it will mark as 1 otherwise 0. But I don't know how to match N_id to colnames(res) and fill the data
what modification is required in the code.

Expected output :- 
[image]

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listfile                                     #contain list of all files
ID                                           #contain ID of all products
N <- read.csv("/home/folder/Noah.csv")
N_ID <- N$product_ID               
library(stringi)
c <- stri_count_regex(ID, paste(N_id, collapse = '|'))
print(c)
```